# redirect all pages including sub pages to new domain

Tags: mod-rewrite

I tried this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*) http://olddomain.com$1
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But all subpages are not redirected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting directive `AllowOverride All` in your Apache config?
Is the mod_rewrite module working?

Comment: Please note that `AllowOverride All` is only on apache 2.2 and older

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine On 
# Take care of www.old.com.au
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.com.au$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.com/$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^attachment_id=([0-9]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.new.com/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, I was just using this to do some special rewriting for my own, here is your code:

Put this inside your /www/.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

// Rules to redirect to another domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.net/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Check http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/setting-up-a-301-permanent-redirect-via-htaccess, for 3 more ways to make a redirection.